# Artifacts when 2 semitransparent planes intersects in RealityKit2

Tags: shader, scenekit, transparency, realitykit

I want to place some semitransparent stickers on my wall using RealityKit2. Sticker Entity is just a plane with SimpleMaterial:

```
var simpleMaterial = SimpleMaterial()
simpleMaterial.color = try! SimpleMaterial.BaseColor.init(tint: .white.withAlphaComponent(0.9999), texture: MaterialParameters.Texture.init(RealityFoundation.TextureResource.generate(from: image.cgImage!, withName: nil, options: TextureResource.CreateOptions.init(semantic: nil))))
self.model = ModelComponent(mesh: .generatePlane(width: 0.3, depth: 0.3 / Float(aspectRatio)), materials: [material])
```

But if there is some intersection between planes sometimes I see some artifacts where part of an entity is invisible [image]
[image]

I'm looking for a way to

1. (best case) Set some rendering order (1 layer always rendered first and second is rendered on top of that) and be able to change it.
2. Fix the problem with intersection ([video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15EkP38F-5kjCFQ0g0kJ5XGOWB1wO342m/view?usp=sharing)) where none of entity fragments is discarded.

For now I'm using RealityKit, but I can switch to SceneKit if it's impossible here.

Comment: Coult it be, that you have some kind of Z-Fight issue? What if you place a small distance, like one cm between the two planes?

Comment: I tried with 10cm between planes. In that case I can see this problem less often but it's still reproducible.

Comment: Hard to tell... what happens if you do it with Scenekit (in combination with ARKit?)

Comment: I can replicate best case scenario with 2 SCNNodes using different rendering order and by disabling "writesToDepthBuffer" option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't render transparent objects like this with depth-testing enabled as the full plane will be rasterized to the depth buffer regardless of the alpha value you write, causing fragments to be regarded as occluded when they really aren't. There's several approaches to mitigate this issue:

- Discard fragments below a certain threshold alpha value using the `discard` keyword
- Sort alpha blended planes by distance to the camera
- More complex solutions like:

  - Depth Peeling
  - Various Order-Independent-Transparency solutions

Comment: Do you know of any ways to achieve any of these using RealityKit? I'm trying to do pretty much exactly what OP is trying to do, but I really don't want to rewrite in SceneKit. I haven't found any way to manually sort Entities (I am happy to sort by time added, which is easier than testing distance to camera), and the CustomMaterial shader seems to be not flexible enough for me to implement blending/z-index myself.